# PHP MySQL Select where product has both filters

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I am trying to get the product that has both filters in URL

for example i have : www.example.com/product-name?filters=181,156

I need to select from database the product that has both of the values.

The Filters table is in 3 columns

thanks

LE:
filters table looks like:

id | product_id | values
1 | 841 | 181
2 | 841 | 156

What I need is SELECT product_id FROM filters WHERE values = 181 AND values = 156

I tried with IN but is not what i need, in is making OR not AND

Comment: Have you tried to read mysql manuals?

Comment: yes, did not find any help

Comment: Have you tried any queries? Show them please

Comment: What have you tried already? What is `filter`(Is it an id), what is stored in `values`, what is the data type of `values`, ... ? Show some sample data.

Comment: I tried with IN () but that acts like an OR not an AND

Comment: i put an edit in the post

Comment: You'll probably need a self-join or to join the filter table to the product table twice.  There's plenty of tutorials on how to do those.

Comment: I can't write an answer right now. But you could check the `values` against the `filter` using `OR` group it by `product_id` and use `HAVING` to just display where the `COUNT` of the group by equals the number of filter elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try below examples (demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1de9c9/8 )

A first one is using EXISTS operator

```
SELECT distinct product_id
FROM filters f
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT id FROM filters f1
      WHERE f.product_id = f1.product_id
        AND f1.`values` = 181
   )
 AND
   EXISTS (
      SELECT id FROM filters f1
      WHERE f.product_id = f1.product_id
        AND f1.`values` = 156
   )
;
```

A second one with JOIN operator

```
SELECT f1.product_id
FROM filters f1
JOIN filters f2
ON f1.product_id = f2.product_id
WHERE
  f1.`values` = 181
  AND
  f2.`values` = 156;
```

A third one using GROUP BY and HAVING

```
SELECT product_id
FROM filters
WHERE `values` IN (181,156)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
;
```